# AggregateRating not showing in Google's rich snippet testing tool

Tags: php, wordpress, rich-snippets, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I tried using the `AggregateRating` and used the code below. The values of `$aggregate_rating` and `$total_reviews` is not empty, and tried printing its value.

Now I added the code inside my WordPress post, and checked the preview on Google's rich snippet testing tool.  `AggregateRating` is not showing.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoRepair">
    <strong><span itemprop="name">GMD Auto Shop</span></strong>
    [php]
        echo "<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">". $aggregate_rating . " </span> stars for <span itemprop="reviewCount">" . 
        $total_reviews . "</span></div>reviews.";
    [/php]        
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">Kamagong Street, Lahug</span>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">Cebu City</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion"> Cebu</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">6000</span>
    </div>
    Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">032-417-4700</span>
    <div itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">Latitude: 40 deg 44 min 54.36 sec N
        Longitude: 123° 54.037'
        <meta itemprop="latitude" content="40.75" />
        <meta itemprop="longitude" content="54.98" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although `http://schema.org/AutoRepair` is a valid itemtype, in my experience any itemtype other than `http://schema.org/Product` does not show in the rich snippet testing tool. I find this frustrating as it means listing organisations as products. Although the above will get your rating shown in the snippets tool, I am interested to know if there is a solution that allows us to use the correct itemtype and see a rating in the rich snippets tool.

Comment: Your PHP code looks invalid.   `[php]` should be `<?php>`.  Also, you are using a double quoted string with double quotes inside it.  There is no way that what you pasted in would print out valid markup that Google's tool could understand.

Comment: I am using a plugin in wordpress that enables the php code inserted inside a post. `[php]` is like a short code.

Comment: You should show us the actual HTML (only this can be checked in Google’s Testing Tool), *after* PHP was executed.

Answer (score 1):

@lordzden your PHP as Stephen points out is invalid. Your echo should look like

```
<?php
$aggregate_rating = '6.5';
$total_reviews = '24';

echo '<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"><span itemprop="ratingValue">'. $aggregate_rating .'</span> stars for <span itemprop="reviewCount">'. $total_reviews . '</span></div>reviews';
?>
```

Comment: He/she is using shortcode... in WordPress

Comment: @bybe I know that they are using a shortcode plugin. They seem to be a little familiar with PHP enough to know that my open and close tags would need to be replaced with their shortcode.